# Do Tomb Raider: Anniversary and Tomb Raider: Legend use the same engine?

Tags: pc, tomb-raider-anniversary

Do *Tomb Raider: Legend*, and *Tomb Raider: Anniversary* use the same game engine? The character models definitely look the same.

*Legend*'s has a feature called "Next-Generation graphics." Is there a way to turn it on in *Anniversary*?

Answer (score 2):

As said, both uses the same engine but Legend came first than Anniversary so you can expect a few aces not available on Anniversary that are present on Legend (i.e. next generation content).

Maybe you don't know this but Anniversary it's a remake of the first Tomb Raider, so yes, it use the same Legend model for Lara, but not so much for enemies.

So far, the only main differences I have noted is that Lara doesn't have a flashlight in Anniversary, nor binoculars, she can't stand top of swing poles and jump from them, no PDA (you have a journal instead, but it's far less useful), no bike sequences, magnetic hook in mansion looks more like a grappling hook even when it do the same, next generation content can't be enabled, PC port is badly optimised, as consequence the game will run worst at same settings used in legend. Besides that, it's pretty much the same game mechanics...

Comment: I can't understand your first sentence. What is "spect"? And I wouldn't expect the later game to have *fewer* "aces"...

Comment: @ERJ: Sorry, I mean expect, bad typo. And about having less tricks (or aces in the hole), just look what I posted before. No flashlight (nor flares, so you must endure any lack of lightning, but thats not really a problem because unlike TR1, Anniversary don't put you in complete dark rooms), there are no binoculars so you can sneak from long distances, she can swing on horizontal poles but she can stand top of them and jump like in Legend; journal instead of PDA, no bike, no nexgen content... thats a quite lack of tricks, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

More or less same graphics engine. More or less the same player models. But all the levels are different (more or less the levels from the original game, massively updated with new technology and tricks they just couldn't pull off in the old engine) and Lara has a slightly different bag of tricks (pole balancing, assisted wall running, etc).

Calling it "the same game" is doing both a disservice.

Comment: I assume you mean *Anniversary* has the different bag of tricks?

Comment: The word "different" implicitly refers two at least two things that aren't the same as one another. Anniversary's has different tricks from Legend's Lara; Legend's Lara has different tricks from Anniversary's Lara.

Comment: Could you expand on that? You are saying that *Legend* doesn't have wall-running & pole-balancing? If so, does it have any other mechanics that *Anniversary* doesn't?

Comment: Lara's grapple in Legend is magnetic, which lets her do certain things she can't in Anniversary. Also - but don't quote me on this - Anniversary lacks motorcycle sequences.

Comment: You're right, there aren't any motorcycles in Anniversary. But I'm pretty sure the grapple is magnetic...